# Como usar em uma string que contenha aspas dupla em seu conteúdo junto com o marcador @

Tags: c#, .net

Estou criando um teste unitário simples que compare duas strings e gostaria de usar o marcador `@` para deixar o conteúdo de uma string formatado em várias linhas como a seguir:

```
   var esperado =  @"123|teste|teste|\"GET / algunNomeDeRquivo.txt HTTP / 1.1\"|100.2
    453| 404| MISS | \"POST /myImages HTTP/1.1\" | 999
    199 | 404 | MISS | \"GET /testte HTTP/1.1" | 999
    312 | 201| TESTE| "GET /teste.txt HTTP/1.1\" | 999";
```

Porém quando adiciono o marcador `@` o mesmo reconhece a aspas dentro da string como marcador final da mesma. Existe alguma forma de manter o `@` em strings que tenham em seu conteúdo aspas duplas?

Comment: só colocar duas `""` ... `@"123|teste|teste|""GET..."`

Comment: Também pode utilizar StringBuilder, pra separar por linhas pra organizar, exemplo:
StringBuilder esperado = new StringBuilder();
esperado.Append("123|teste|teste\"GET / algumNomeDeArquivo.txt HTTP / 1.1\" |100.2");

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Utilize duas aspas duplas no corpo da string, por exemplo:

```
var esperado = @"123|teste|teste|""GET / algunNomeDeRquivo.txt HTTP / 1.1\""|100.2
                453 | 404 | MISS | \""POST /myImages HTTP/1.1\"" | 999
                199 | 404 | MISS | \""GET /testte HTTP/1.1"" | 999
                312 | 201 | TESTE | ""GET /teste.txt HTTP/1.1\"" | 999";
```